# Error in Upgrading, Removing MySQL connector

Tags: mysql-connector

I can't upgrade or remove the MySQL connector/net 8.0.21. This is log. Does anyone know why I need to do to upgrade it?

```
1: Action 14:16:48: INSTALL. 
1: 1: MySQL Connector Net 8.0.21 2: {B76BB4C5-40E4-4D2C-8A18-8C85C304D084} 
1: Action 14:16:48: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 14:16:48: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Action 14:16:48: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
1: Action 14:16:48: ValidateProductID. 
1: Action 14:16:48: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 14:16:48: FileCost. Computing space requirements
1: Action 14:16:48: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 14:16:48: InstallValidate. Validating install
1: Action 14:16:48: Setv45InstallUtil. 
1: Action 14:16:48: InstallInitialize. 
1: Action 14:16:48: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
1: Application: {0160C4A1-392C-4AFA-B8DB-2471FDA71425}, Command line: UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE={B76BB4C5-40E4-4D2C-8A18-8C85C304D084} CLIENTPROCESSID=59360 CLIENTUILEVEL=3 MSICLIENTUSESEXTERNALUI=1 REMOVE=ALL
1: The older version of MySQL Connector Net 8.0.21 cannot be removed.  Contact your technical support group.  
1: 1: MySQL Connector Net 8.0.21 2: {B76BB4C5-40E4-4D2C-8A18-8C85C304D084} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Upgrade' for product 'Connector/NET 8.0.21' failed.
```

Comment: is it some in use, even after a restart

Comment: can't upgrade even after a restart.

Comment: write a bugtracker ticket with oracle, if event viewer and doesn't show a cause. I couldn't update the server, and had to reinsll the hole machine

Answer (score 0):

By any chance did you manually changed the installation before trying to upgrade?
There’s one bug related to that maybe could help you to resolve your issue: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101060
If you still can't fix your problem you can raise a bug in bugs.mysql.com, just ensure to provide more details about what steps you followed to fall in that problem,
I mean, something to help to reproduce the problem, like describe if you tried this from MySqlInstaller or if you tried from the MSI, or any other detail that you consider could affect.